# How use cdkDropListConnectedTo cdkDropList inside cdkDropList?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material, drag-and-drop

I try but can't connect this cdkDropLists instances together by setting the cdkDropListConnectedTo property or by wrapping the elements in an element with the cdkDropListGroup attribute.
The problem its when You set list inside list. there is no possibility to drag elements

How use cdkDropListConnectedTo cdkDropList inside cdkDropList?

hTML:

```
<div cdkDropListGroup>
  <div class="example-container">
    <div cdkDropList
         [cdkDropListData]="done"
         class="example-list"
         (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
        <div class="example-box" *ngFor="let item of done" cdkDrag>
          {{item.type}}
          <!--**************************************************************************-->
          <div class="example-container">
            <div cdkDropList
                 [cdkDropListData]="item.input"
                 class="example-vert-list"
                 cdkDropListOrientation="horizontal"
                 (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
              <div class="example-box" *ngFor="let item2 of item.input" cdkDrag>
                {{item2.type}}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!--***************************************************************************-->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

TS:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {CdkDragDrop, moveItemInArray, transferArrayItem} from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';
import {DropService} from '../drop.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-editor',
  templateUrl: './editor.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./editor.component.css']
})
export class EditorComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private dropService: DropService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  done: Element[] = [
    {type: '1111', input: []},
    {
      type: '22222', input: [
        {type: 't!!!!!', input: []},
        {type: 't@@@@@', input: []},
        {type: 't####', input: []},
        {type: 't$$$$', input: []}
      ]
    },
    {type: '33333', input: []},
    {
      type: '444444', input: [
        {type: '!!!!!', input: []},
        {type: '@@@@@', input: []},
        {type: '####', input: []},
        {type: '$$$$', input: []}
      ]
    }
  ];

  public drop(event: CdkDragDrop<Element[]>) {
    if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
      moveItemInArray(event.container.data, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
    } else {
      transferArrayItem(event.previousContainer.data,
        event.container.data,
        event.previousIndex,
        event.currentIndex);
    }
  }

}

export interface Element {
  type: string;
  input: Element[];
}
```